# Universal Apps - Catch errors thats occur in the WebView

Tags: c#, webview, win-universal-app

I am currently working on an universal apps that displays a local HTML website through a WebView component.

Currently it does not work because I have some Javascript errors (I am aware of this). When I launch the website on the IE of my PC I have an **Access is denied** error. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn887953(v=vs.94).aspx).

I would like to catch this error in my app in order to obtain a log, but I cannot find a way to catch an error through the WebView component.

There is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this [*How to* page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn715902.aspx) on the Windows Dev Center.